# Дерганье страницы при подгрузке контента

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть страница, где, по идее, организована подгрузка контента без перезагрузки.

Вот он http://delmit.eurodir.ru/kaps/vipolnen.html (потыкать по ссылкам, что над картинками домов).

Почему страница дергается на начало, если переключаться?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.ajaxload').click(function(){
        $('#ajax-wrap #text').load($(this).attr('href')+" #text");
        History.replaceState('null', $(this).attr('title'), $(this).attr('href'))
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: замените History.replaceState на history.pushState

Comment: Дёргается на начало, потому что у вас страница перезагружается при каждом нажатии

Comment: т.е. получается, что нет у меня ни акой перезагрузки без обновления?

Comment: @woland изменение на history.pushState. помогает странице не дергаться, но и контент не меняется, только адрес в строке